# Preferred app navigation design/layout in this case?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

I am confusing about how to design 1. the category view and 2. the detail/edit view for my app. What is the preferred way/best practice in such a case like this? (sorry for the "text hierarchy" below, but I'm a new user here and not allowed to post images yet).

HOME
|-
 
    |- Add car
    |- Choose car
     |- Category 1
        |- View 1
          |- Edit 1
     |- Category 2
        |- View 2
     |- Category 3
        |- View 3
        |- Add 3
        |- Statistics 3
     |- Category 4
        |- View 4
        |- Add 4
     |- Category 5
       |- View 5

Current app structure:
I have a top level view with two choices: adding a new car or choose an existing. I'm using ActionBarSherlock all over the app.

If a car was chosen, the category view appears with one imagebutton for each category. The navigation hierarchy is simple for "Category 1", "Category 2" and "Category 5", but deeper for "Category 3 and 4".

Currently, when touching the imagebutton for "Category 4 or 5", a popup-menu appears. If "Category 4" was chosen, "Add", "View" and "Statistics" can be chosen from the popup menu.

Alternative app structure:
I have thought of several designs for the category view, since I'm not completely satisfied with the popup menu here.

Alternative 1:
Still use imagebuttons for categories, BUT without popup menu. Instead if the user touches the "Category 3" button, the "view-activity" for category 3 should be shown. 
Then the "Add-" and "Statistics" activities can be reached from icons in the ActionBar (top level action bar), OR from an ActionBar below the top-level ActionBar, using fixed tabs.
A disadvantage with this alternative is that you must go to the view activity first, even though you may want to go to the "add activity" immediately.

Alternative 2:
At the category view, place each category in the ActionBar using scrolling tabs. I don't actually satisfied with this alternative, since I have five categories not releated so much to each other. So all of them should be visible at the same time.

Alternative 3:
At the category view, use some kind of multi-pane view for selecting each of the categories.

At the moment, I'm thinking most of alternative 1, either with the "detail/edit view" reachable from top-level ActionBar, or by fixed tabs ActionBar.

What do you think is best practice for my case? One of my alternatives or do you have a better idea? I have read the Android design guidelines and such, but find it kind of hard to decide which way to go.

Comment: A subjective opinion: it depends on multiple variables.  Say, how many items are there in a category, how often the user switches categories, browsing through how many items they are comfortable with, etc. So one approach would be to ask and answer questions like those.

Comment: Category 1: one item, info about the chosen car. Category 2: Google Maps activity. Category 3: not much in the "add" activity, a lot (list) will be in the "view" activity, the "stats" activity now contains stats in table format, not many items at all here. Same goes for Category 4. Finally Category 5 only consists of some contacts, but I think I'll refactor this activity later on. The user will most likely visit the "add" activity for Category 3 and 4 most of the time. Sometimes the "view" part of them. Category 3 and 4 will most likely not be used at the same time, so not a lot of switching.

Comment: Well, still going to be subjective anyway.  I would play the real user and count clicks / scrolls for various scenarios, including restarts, such as leaving the app and coming back (e.g., a phone call).  Last but not least: if you know upfront that the two Add actions will be most used, why not stick them just in the front view?  That would break the tree structure - so what?  Maybe a combination of "expanded" and "collapsed" branches immediately available to the user would be a good alternative (#3?).